# Windows Sandbox can not launch with error 0xffffffff

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v, windows-10-v20h2, windows-sandbox

I can not launch Windows Sandbox after upgrade to 21H1, it shows a Windows Sandbox failed to start. (0xffffffff) error. I find someone also asked about this issue in the [Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-sandbox-failed-to-start-0xffffffff/60338434-e4b5-4406-8c84-2c4f924fec6d), but it did not get solved. So is there a chance anyone knows how to resolve this issue?

[[image: error]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue seems to be self-solving after <strike>installing **WSL** and **Virtual Platform**.</strike> stop custom DNS service.

Comment: Could you please add some more detail? Exactly what did you have to do to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Stop any non-Microsoft DNS service on your computer ( run - `service.msc` and find your service, in my case is Acrylic DNS Proxy ) before launching Windows Sandbox, once Windows Sandbox is showing up, you can start your DNS service again.